# read/write to the same file (getting gmon.out)

Tags: c++, file-io

My homework asks that I use a single file to output data to, send calculations to that file, and read the results from that file.
The data is a series of input ages from 1-100, controlled by a decrement counter based off of a variable cin by user: totalAges.

The problem I'm having is that the file is not being created as variable.txt
it is gmon.out.

i've looked at a bunch of tutorials tried to troubleshoot myself, tried to use fstream/ofstream/ifstream etc... I can't figure it out. How can I get it to first write the data to a file, then read FROM that file?

The error i'm mostly getting is:

```
data>>age; 
No match for 'operator>>'.
```

AND

```
132 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-        mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setbase)
```

^^ that happens a bunch which i'm thinking is trying to use ofstream with
ios::in.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this task.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int totalAges;
int age;
string str_fileIn;
int average = 0;


cout<<"Enter a filename.\n";
cin>>str_fileIn;

ofstream data;
data.open //this may be the problem but i'm not sure why exactly.
    ((str_fileIn+".txt").c_str(), ios::in | ios::out);

counter = totalAges;

for (counter; counter>=1; --counter)
{
    cout<<"Enter an age value 1-100. ";

    cin>>age;
average = average + age;
}

average = average /totalAges;
highest = age;
lowest = age;

  while(data.is_open())
   { 
   if (age > highest)
      {highest = age;}

   if (age < lowest)
      {lowest = age;}
data>>age;  //this operator will not work here!
counter++;

if (counter==totalAges)
   data.close();
}
```

Sorry If i missed something crucial I tried to include as much info as possible while not being a textbook.

Thank you.

Error List:

```
 D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp   In function 'int main()':

 104    6   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Error] no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' and 'int')

104 6   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] candidates are:

53  0   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\string  In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/string

40      C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\locale_classes.h                    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h

41      C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h                  from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h

42      C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\ios                  from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/ios

38      C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\ostream                  from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/ostream

39      C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iostream                     from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream

22      D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp                     from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

996 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\basic_string.tcc   [Note] template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)

996 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\basic_string.tcc   [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

104 8   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'

879 0   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\istream In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/istream

40      C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iostream                     from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream

22      D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp                     from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

955 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\istream.tcc    [Note] template<class _CharT2, class _Traits2> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT2*)
```

955  5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\istream.tcc    [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

```
104 8   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'

879 0   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\istream In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/istream

40      C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iostream                     from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream

22      D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp                     from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

923 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\istream.tcc    [Note] template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT&)

923 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\istream.tcc    [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

104 8   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'

40  0   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iostream    In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream

 22     D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp                     from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

727 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\istream [Note] template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char&)

727 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\istream [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

104 8   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>'

40  0   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iostream    In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream

22      D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp                     from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

732 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\istream [Note] template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char&)

732 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\istream [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

104 8   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>'

40  0   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iostream    In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream

22      D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp                     from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

774 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\istream [Note] template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char*)

774 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\istream [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

104 8   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>'

40  0   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iostream    In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream

22      D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp                     from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

779 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\istream [Note] template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char*)

779 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\istream [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

104 8   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>'

23  0   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    In file included from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

71  5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Resetiosflags)

71  5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

104 8   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'

23  0   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    In file included from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

101 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setiosflags)

101 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

104 8   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'

23  0   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    In file included from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

132 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setbase)

132 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

104 8   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'

23  0   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    In file included from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

170 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setfill<_CharT>)

170 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

104 8   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'

23  0   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    In file included from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

200 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setprecision)
```

200  5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

```
104 8   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'

23  0   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    In file included from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

230 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setw)

230 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

104 8   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'

122 9   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Error] no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' and 'int')

122 9   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] candidates are:

53  0   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\string  In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/string

40      C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\locale_classes.h                    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h

41      C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h                  from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h

42      C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\ios                  from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/ios

38      C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\ostream                  from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/ostream

39      C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iostream                     from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream

22      D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp                     from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

 996    5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\basic_string.tcc   [Note] template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)

996 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\basic_string.tcc   [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

122 11  D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'

879 0   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\istream In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/istream

40      C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iostream                     from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream

22      D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp                     from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

955 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\istream.tcc    [Note] template<class _CharT2, class _Traits2> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT2*)

955 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\istream.tcc    [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

 122    11  D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'

879 0   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\istream In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/istream

40      C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iostream                     from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream

22      D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp                     from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

923 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\istream.tcc    [Note] template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT&)

923 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\istream.tcc    [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

122 11  D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'

40  0   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iostream    In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream

22      D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp                     from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

727 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\istream [Note] template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char&)

727 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\istream [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

122 11  D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>'

40  0   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iostream    In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream

 22     D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp                     from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

 732    5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\istream [Note] template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char&)

732 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\istream [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

122 11  D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>'

40  0   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iostream    In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream

22      D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp                     from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

774 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\istream [Note] template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char*)

774 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\istream [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

122 11  D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>'

40  0   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iostream    In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream

22      D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp                     from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

779 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\istream [Note] template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char*)

779 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\istream [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

122 11  D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>'

23  0   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    In file included from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

71  5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Resetiosflags)

71  5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

122 11  D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'

23  0   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    In file included from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

101 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setiosflags)

101 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

122 11  D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'

23  0   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    In file included from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

132 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setbase)

132 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

122 11  D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'

23  0   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    In file included from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

170 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setfill<_CharT>)

170 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-  mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip   [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

122  11  D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'

```
 23 0   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    In file included from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

  200   5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setprecision)

   200  5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:

122 11  D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'

 23 0   D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    In file included from D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp

230 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setw)

230 5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\iomanip [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:


122 11  D:\Fall16_CIT133\HW5\COPY5001198106L_Chisholm_HW5_Q3.cpp    [Note] 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>'
```

edit 1: added #include -- and compiler error list

Comment: Where are your `#include`s?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a copy-paste dump of the *complete* output from the compiler, in full and without editing. And include possible informational notes.

Comment: if you want to open a file you use  <fcntl.h>  and call **fd = open("arguments")** then read(fd, "arguments") and write(fd, "arguments) for IO. http://www.gdsw.at/languages/c/programming-bbrown/c_075.htm

Comment: Use `fstream` instead of `ofstram`

Comment: Okay so i changed data to an fstream it runs but the file is still a gmon.out I made sure that the first thing I did was open the file. Should i still be using <fcntl.h> and the calll fd = open ("arguments") ?

Comment: is there no other way to make the file a txt Not a gmon.out and read/write? i'm using Dev C++ IDE, is there an option in there for conversion or something?

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
data>>age;
```

you are trying to read from the *output* stream. You should be using `<<` to write instead:

```
data<<age;
```

Before that though, you need to check if the file actually is open, or any writing to it will not work. You also need to make sure the file is created where you *think* it is created. It might not where you expect it to be, so search for it.

Answer (score -1):

The `gmon.out` file is the [output from the `gprof` runtime profiling tool](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/Executing.html). You must have enabled `gprof` profiling in your compilation settings. It has nothing to do with your output file.

Your output file is being created, if it gets created at all, in the directory where your executable gets executed from. Which is not necessarily the same directory with your source files are, or the directory where the executable gets created. Check your compiler settings to determine which directory your executable runs from, and you should find your `variable.txt` file there.

Comment: the compiler error is generated because `ofstream` does not have `operator>>`.